# How can i recieve pushed message from google pubsub

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I Have created new topic and new subscription and set delivery type: push and set end point `URL` :

**index.php :**

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    $data = json_encode($_POST);
    print_R($data);
    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

When publish message i want to process the data from this end point as an example save data to file.

the file is created but with empty `array []`.

any issue in my `php` `code`, does the data store in `$_POST` or i need to use another way.

Comment: No one can help on this!

Answer (score 0):

To fetch Pub/Sub messages, you need to use the Google Pub/Sub library. Given that you've set your subscription endpoint to your URL, the code should look like something similar to this:

```
use Google\Cloud\PubSub\PubSubClient;

$projectId = "YOUR-PROJECT-ID";
$subscriptionName = "YOUR-SUBSCRIPTION-NAME";

$pubsub = new PubSubClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
$subscription = $pubsub->subscription($subscriptionName);

$pullMessages = [];
foreach ($subscription->pull(['returnImmediately' => true]) as $pullMessage) {
    $pullMessages[] = $pullMessage;
    $msg = $pullMessage->data();

    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($fp, $msg);
    fclose($fp);
}

// acknowledge PULL messages
if ($pullMessages) {
    $subscription->acknowledgeBatch($pullMessages);
}
```

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/pubsub/app). As well as a more in-detail explanation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push).